# Prevent cache values in the browser

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, icefaces

I have a `selectOneMenu` and a `dataTable`. When I change the selected value, `dataTable` will repopulate.
A one of column of the `dataTable` is an `inputText`. The problem is that the `inputText` field doesn't call the `getter`, but caches the previous value.

I want to either call the `getter` by force or set `inputText` to not be cached.
How do I get rid of this problem?

```
 <h:body>
     <f:view>
         <h:form id="headForm">

            <ice:selectOneMenu id="item"
                    value="#{outerBean.selectedItem}"
                    valueChangeListener="#{outerBean.itemListValueChanged}"
                    style="width: 158px;" required="true"
                    label="Supplier Id" partialSubmit="true">
                    <f:selectItems value="#{outerBean.itemList}" />
            </ice:selectOneMenu>

            <ice:dataTable id="pdet" value="#{outerBean.nestedClassList}" var="nestedObject" rendered="true">

                <ice:column>
                <f:facet name="header">Order Number</f:facet>
                    <ice:outputText value="#{nestedObject.orderNumber}" />
                </ice:column>

                <ice:column>
                <f:facet name="header">Qty</f:facet>
                    <ice:inputText value="#{nestedObject.qty}" id="qty" label="'Qty' FOR 'Order Number':#{nestedObject.orderNumber} "
                                   partialSubmit="true" 
                                   valueChangeListener="#{nestedObject.qtyChanged}"
                                   validator="#{nestedObject.validateQty}">
                    </ice:inputText>
                 </ice:column>
            </ice:dataTable>
       </h:form>
   </h:view>
```

```
public class OuterBean{

    private List<String> itemList = new ArrayList<String>();
    private String selectedItem;

    private List<NestedClass> nestedClassList = new ArrayList<NestedClass>();

    public OuterBean(){
         //init values
    }

    public void itemListValueChanged(ValueChangeEvent e){
         selectedItem = (String)e.getNewValue();

         //reset the dataTable record list
         nestedClassList = getRandomRecords();
    }

    //---getters-setters-----//

    private class NestedClass{

         private int orderNumber;
         private int qty;

         NestedClass(){
             orderNumber = generateOrderNumber();
             qty = getRandomQty();
         }

         //-----qtyChangedListener----//
         //-----qtyValidator----------//
         //-----getters-setters-------//
     }
}
```

Comment: For more clarification show us snippets of code

Answer (score 0):

I don't see where you are chainging nestedObject.qty in itemListValueChanged

The component will not rerender unless it is changed .

Partial Submit in Icefaces will only update the components whose value have changed.

You can make Partial Submit false on selectonemenu or you can reinitialize the value of the inputText in itemListValueChanged.

Comment: I'm adding list of `nestedObject`s. So each `nestedObject` has a property called `qty`. So it is a new value.

Comment: can you monitor the request receive-updated-views which will be called by Icefaces to update monitor. Which version of icefaces you are using ?